# how to make dropdown cell overlapping uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a custom button setup programmatically the setup more like wrapping uiview with UIButton, when I touch it show a list of names. and the problem is in my view controller under the custom button there is a uiview, when I try to tap the button. my list is behind the uiview. how can I make the list is over uiview this is my UI and my code setup.

see there is a list of hello and world, but the world is cover with uiview.

[image: listdropdown]

This is my code setup

```
    class AddScheduleViewController: UIViewController {

    let containerTitle      = GView(bgColor: .white, radius: 0)
    let headerView          = HeaderView()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scrollView
    }()

    var chooseScheduleDropDown = GDropdownSchedule(type: .system)
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        chooseScheduleDropDown = GDropdownSchedule.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        chooseScheduleDropDown.dropView.options = ["Hello", "World"]
        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        view.addSubview(containerTitle)
        containerTitle.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        containerTitle.clipsToBounds = true
        containerTitle.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, topPadding: 16, rightPadding: 19, bottomPadding: 16, leftPadding: 19, width: 0, height: 0)

        containerTitle.addSubview(headerView)
        headerView.anchor(top: containerTitle.topAnchor, trailing: containerTitle.trailingAnchor, bottom: nil, leading: containerTitle.leadingAnchor, topPadding: 0, rightPadding: 0, bottomPadding: 0, leftPadding: 0, width: 0, height: 53)

        containerTitle.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.anchor(top: headerView.bottomAnchor, trailing: containerTitle.trailingAnchor, bottom: containerTitle.bottomAnchor, leading: containerTitle.leadingAnchor, topPadding: 8, rightPadding: 8, bottomPadding: 8, leftPadding: 8, width: 0, height: 0)

        [chooseScheduleDropDown, entryView, chooseDateView, chooseClass, startTimeView, endTimeView, descriptionView, saveBtn].forEach {
            v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            scrollView.addSubview(v)
        }

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            chooseScheduleDropDown.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
            chooseScheduleDropDown.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            chooseScheduleDropDown.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 285),
            chooseScheduleDropDown.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),

            entryView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
            entryView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: chooseScheduleDropDown.bottomAnchor, constant: topPadding),
            entryView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 285),
            entryView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "list" is a subclass of `UIView` (or a table view, whatever), and it has also been added as a subview of your `scrollView`, you can bring it in front of other subviews with:

```
scrollView.bringSubviewToFront(entryView)
```

As a side note, a couple tips:

- Try to start with simple elements.

  - Use plain `UIView` object (give them different background colors), so you have less code to deal with.
  - Once you have the basic task worked out, add in your "custom" elements.
- When asking questions here on StackOverflow,

  - Try to include enough code so someone can copy/paste and run it to help figure out what's going on. For example, nobody can know what your `GView`, `HeaderView` and `GDropdownSchedule` objects are.
  - Try to avoid things like your `.anchor()` extension. It is rather difficult to scroll horizontally through all the parameters (one of your lines is 308 characters long) to understand what constraints are being set.

Comment: Hey @DonMag you a live saver, I wish have mentor like you. and thank you for the note, and for asking in stack overflow. I want to add my code of GDropdownSchedule, since it's a long line. I know stack overflow will complain it has too many code. so that's why I can't add much

Comment: I don't understand when I try to tap my tableview, the second cell not responding to tap. only the first cell I'm able to tap. I try using your method and use layer.zPosition and UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.bringSubviewsToFront still not want to tap the second cell

Comment: *"try to tap my tableview, the second cell not responding"* ... tough to say without more detail. What is your *tableview*? Is that a subview you are showing that was partially behind other views? It that tableview working if you have it in a view by itself, without the other view? Maybe try to put together a [mcve] that you can post to GitHub or zip up and file-share it.